# Archlinux: cant install vpcs - error: conflicting types for ‘getopt’

Tags: gcc, archlinux

I am trying to install vpcs in Archlinux (needed for the GNS3) but the following error appears after I run makepkg command:

```
**In file included from hv.c:45:0:
./getopt.h:53:5: error: conflicting types for ‘getopt’
 int getopt(int argc, char** argv, char* optstr);
     ^~~~~~**
In file included from /usr/include/bits/getopt_posix.h:27:0,
                 from /usr/include/unistd.h:872,
                 from hv.c:33:
/usr/include/bits/getopt_core.h:91:12: note: previous declaration of ‘getopt’ was here
 extern int getopt (int ___argc, char *const *___argv, const char *__shortopts)
            ^~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile.linux:38: hv.o] Error 1
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

Tried to google the issue - no luck. Any help?

Comment: Can you provide details of what you have done so far? A link to the pkg or PKGBUILD may help. Asking the package maintainer or posting in arch forums may get you to a solution faster. Just a guess.. It looks like `getopt` was declared in multiple places, possibly a mix of c and c++?

Comment: Hi. Well, nothing special. I have used a git clone command to grab the vpcs source from the git url. Then I've executed makepkg command to build the package but the given error occurred. I can copy~paste whole process if neccessary?

Comment: There's an equal issue in github but nobody has answered (yet):
https://github.com/GNS3/vpcs/issues/13

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but finally solved.

```
$ sudo pacman -S subversion
$ cd /tmp
$ svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/vpcs/code/trunk vpcs-code
$ cd vpcs-code/src
$ rgetopt='int getopt(int argc, char *const *argv, const char *optstr);'
$ sed -i "s/^int getopt.*/$rgetopt/" getopt.h
$ unset -v rgetopt
$ sed -i 's/i386/x86_64/' Makefile.linux
$ sed -i 's/-s -static//' Makefile.linux
$ make -f Makefile.linux
$ strip --strip-unneeded vpcs
$ sudo mv vpcs /usr/local/bin
```

([Source](http://binarynature.blogspot.com/2015/11/install-configure-gns3-arch-linux.html))